# Find events probability ratio

Tags: probability, combinatorics, contest-math

Anti-spam system with 99% chance correctly recognizes spam(while on the other hand in 1% of cases non-spam is being blocked by this system). If it is known that 0.1% of all messages are spam ones, what is the ratio of the following probabilities: "non-spam message is blocked" and "spam message is blocked", if the considered file was blocked(recognized by anti-spam system as spam)?
P.S Can't even build up all of the possible cases and their chance to happen, as system seems to bee too complex.

Comment: There are only 4 possible cases: Spam+Blocked, Spam+Not Blocked, Nonspam+Blocked, Nonspam+Not Blocked. This is the simplest possible illustration of a conditional probability system. What have you tried?

Comment: It is not clear, whether I should keep in mind probability of facing up with the spam or non-spam message. Like, I have some assumptions about that ration, being equal to: (0.999*0.01)/(0.001*0.99)=9.99/0.99. However my teacher told me that they are not really correct..

Comment: What is the chance that spam will make it through (not get blocked)? You show a full breakdown that if a message is blocked, there is a 99% chance that it is spam and a 1% chance it is not. There is a 0.1% chance that an email is spam, but it does not discuss the chance of a message getting blocked or not (regardless of whether it is spam or not).

Comment: @InterstellarProbe, as far as I understand the task, it is highly likely that spam messaged will be blocked(99% of all cases), however 1% of non-spam messages will be blocked too. But it still remains not that clear to me..

Comment: @9cloudalpha what I am saying is that the problem is incomplete. It is missing information. We can make assumptions: We can assume that 99% of all spam messages are caught and 1% are not, and 99% of non-spam messages make it while 1% are caught by the spam filter. This is a poor assumption. It is highly unlikely that a spam filter will catch an exactly equal number of non-spam to the spam it is failing to catch.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe, oh, I got you. I believe such details doesn't matter in terms of math "ideal" world.

Comment: Great point by @InterstellarProbe. The fact that the system correctly recognizes spam 99% of the time does not imply that 1% of non-spam messages get blocked, although it's stated as such in the problem definition. The probabilities here could be made more explicit - does that first sentence mean that 99% of spam messages get blocked, or that 99% of blocked messages are spam? They are not the same at all, and it's not clear which you mean. These details absolutely matter to be able to solve this problem.

Comment: @9cloudalpha When I make a 2x2 contingency table the values of the row/column "no-spam" cannot be calculated.

Comment: @NuclearWang, I think that first sentences states the following: 99% of spam is being blocked.

Comment: @9cloudalpha That would have been my interpretation as well. The second half of that sentence just happens to mislead a little since 99%+1%=100%, falsely suggesting a connection between those values. We may happen to see that 1% of non-spam gets blocked, but it has no relation whatsoever to the fact that 99% of spam gets blocked. The way its written implies a connection between the 99% and the 1%, but that could have just as easily been 2%, or 10%, or 50%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, you appear to be making the assumptions that among all spam, 99% are blocked while 1% are not blocked. 0.1% of all emails are spam. Writing this out:

$$P(\text{Spam that is blocked}) = 0.99\cdot 0.001 = 0.00099 \\ P(\text{Spam that is not blocked}) = 0.01\cdot 0.001 = 0.00001 \\ P(\text{Non-spam that is blocked}) = 0.01\cdot 0.999 = 0.00999 \\ P(\text{Non-spam that is not blocked}) = 0.99\cdot 0.999 = 0.98901$$

Comment: Hm, btw my colleagues got the same ratios, so maybe teacher is wrong after all, as task may be understood differently..